# Why does setupterm terminate the program?

Tags: c, linux, terminfo

This is sample program from "Beginning Linux Programming" book:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <term.h>
#include <curses.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    setupterm("unlisted", fileno(stdout), (int *)0);
    printf("Done.\n");
    exit(0);
}
```

Running it, I have this result:

```
./badterm 
'unlisted': unknown terminal type.
```

According to setupterm function definition, it must return 0: "No matching entry in terminfo database". Instead of this, program terminates. Why?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks like you asked it to do so. From `man setupterm` on my machine:

> ```
>   If errret is null, setupterm prints an error message  upon  finding  an
>   error and exits.  Thus, the simplest call is:
>
>         setupterm((char *)0, 1, (int *)0);
>
>   which uses all the defaults and sends the output to stdout.
> ```

Presumably, if you want to handle any error return yourself, you must supply a non-NULL pointer value for the `errret` (third) parameter.